# discord.js v12 Role Edits after 10 second intervals

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I want my bot to edit a role's color every 10 seconds. Here is  my code:

```js
client.on("ready", () => {
 const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("729208348884467735");
  if (!Guild) return console.error("Couldn't find the guild.");
 const Role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Admin");
  if (!Role) return console.error("Couldn't find the role.");
 var colors = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9'];
 var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
  Role.edit ({
   color: colors[random]
  })
}, 5000);

client.on("ready", ()  => {
 const Guild = client.guilds.cache.get("729208348884467735");
  var c = ['#8585ff','#fff681','#a073fd','#fd73b9', '#2c2f33', '#99aab5']
 const Role = Guild.roles.cache.find(role => role.name == "Admin");
  var outputc = c[Math.floor(Math.random()*c.length)];
setInterval(() => {
 Role.edit({
   color: outputc
 })
}, 10000); 
  console.log('Sucessfully Changed')
});
```

I want my bot to change it in intervals.. So I added setInterval. However it only changes on startup and then the color doesn't change. Can you help me out? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: That's against Discord's Terms of Service. You will most likely get your bot deleted, or worse, your account will be permanently banned from using Discord's API.

Comment: @Jakye I believe its not against Discord TOS to make you bot to edit a role's color. Such a random color role which changes color everyday. Also if it is against it.. which point of the TOS states so?

Comment: You are doing it every 10 seconds, not every day. I'm not a "law guru" myself, but this [official tweet from Discord](https://twitter.com/discord/status/1055182857709256704) should confirm my point.

Comment: @Jakye So it may be allowed on everyday basis because I wanted to make a random color role so that it changes everyday...